# ASP.NET best way to add/edit record

Tags: asp.net, forms, detailsview

I have a gridview that shows records from a database table. Now, I want to edit records, as well as add some. I've seen that DetailsView is widely used for that purpose. However, it's seems to me that is kind of limited, when talking about design (CSS).

So I ask: what is the best way to add/edit a record? Using this control, or create from scratch a nice fancy form (using jquery, for example)?

Comment: What sort of customer are you writing for? (small company, personal project, big enterprise) How long will the code live for? Will you need to support lots of browsers? (Favors less javascript) Will it need to be maintained by developers less skilled than you? (favors canned controls) Is this an existing app your are extending? (If so, do more of what already exists unless it is really, really bad)  Try a mini form in each style (jquery and detailsview) and see which one was less painful to write.

Comment: Hi Mathew. Thanks for your answer. At this time, I was looking for an easy/quick way to do this. We're talking about an old app that needs some more features. We will develop anther app, so we can't spend too much time on this one. I've managed with custom forms, as you can see in my answer bellow. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this control. There are several methods you can go about using it too. One of the ways, that I usually do (probably a less complex method), is to bind the result set from your query to the gridview, and also have an edit button column where each button corresponds to the same action event in the code-behind. When the user hits the edit button for a given row, you can pull the data from that row and populate input controls on the page, or a different page to be edited by the user (keep track of the record ID they're editing). When they click an "update" button, the program should take the data in the input controls and update the record that is being edited.

I'm sure there are ways to edit a record in the gridview itself, and I plan on learning how to do so soon :p

Comment: Hi Shredder. Thanks for your answer.
Yes, I know I can edit records in the gridview itself, but I don't wnat to do so. I want a form with validation and have full control over its design. I'm not sure DetailsView is the best way to do this...

Comment: ??? That is the answer that I gave you. I *am* talking about a gridview here *and* using other input controls to update records, not the gridview itself. And you can make good use out asp validation controls and your own, and a gridview has lots of styling options. What is the problem?

Comment: Thanks Shredder! I didn't understood your answer first time, don't know why :) Well, I am using customized forms, not the detailsview control. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @escar No problem, hope it helped. And remember to "Mark as Answer" if you feel like it sufficiently answered your question :)